# httpClient.PostAsync(url, content) not working in C# Metro apps

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, http-headers, http-post

I am using `HttpClient.PostAsync()` method to send post request to my web service api. 
I am passing api URL address along with queryString parameters in it..
but `PostAsync()` method is not working correctly, giving an error :

> Status Code 417 expectation failed.

```
    public override async void SendPostRequest(REQUEST_NAME reqName, IDictionary<string, object> args)
    {
        var _client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.example.com/api/v2.0/");
        _client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
        string queryString = "?";
        string url = reqName.ToString() + ".json" + queryString;

        string queryStringparam = "";
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> param in args)
        {
            queryStringparam += param.Key + "=" + param.Value + "&";
        }

       // queryStringparam=name="abc&age=25&event=browsed&url=www.google.com"

       var response = await _client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(queryStringparam));
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {

        }
```

May be I am passing parameters in wrong way in `PostAsync()` method.
Please give me your suggestion about it. Thanks.

Comment: please give your ideas/suggestions asap. thanks,

Comment: Have you tried setting `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue` to `false`?

Comment: Wowwww. just checked by ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue to false & it worked awesome.. thank you so much Stephen Cleary.. :)

Comment: var _client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();   _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false; it worked!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this MSDN forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/60cd6e6a-4157-4811-8ed3-1e46f9022ea8/http-status-417-expectation-failed), this can be caused by proxies that don't support the "100 continue" expectation.

As a workaround, set `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue` or `HttpRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue` to `false`.